# How can I run only single kotlin file in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a problem when i run Kotlin file in Intelij.
I want to run only one kotlin file that is AbstractVehicle.kt
under the image is code of AbstractVhicle.kt

[image]

However, I got an error. because always run with other Kotlin files when I run!!

[image]

I tried to run using variety way to  run only AbstractVehicle.kt file (ex:for example control + shift + R or control + R... My laptop is Macbook )

please help me.. how can run only one kotlin file

Answer (score 0):

First, Click file AbstractVhicle.kt. Second, right click. Third, click run AbstractVhicle main method.